# Why is mapping a single object with Automapper takes more time than mapping 10 or 100?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performance, automapper

**Code used for Analysis:**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using AutoMapper;

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using AutoMapper;

namespace Automapper
{
    class Program
    {
        private List<Customer> _customers = new List<Customer>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var program = new Program();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewItem>();

            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

            for (int x = 1; x <= 100000; x *= 10)
            {
                program.PopulateCustomers(x);

                watch.Start();
                program.RunMapper(x);
                watch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("INITIAL :AutoMapper with {0}: {1}", x, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));



                program.PopulateCustomers(x);

                watch.Start();
                program.RunMapper(x);
                watch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("AutoMapper with {0}: {1}", x, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));

                watch.Reset();

                watch.Start();
                program.RunManual(x);
                watch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Manual Map with {0}: {1}", x, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private void PopulateCustomers(int count)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
            {
                Customer customer = GetCustomerFromDB();
                _customers.Add(customer);
            }
        }

        private void RunMapper(int count)
        {
            List<CustomerViewItem> customers = new List<CustomerViewItem>();
            foreach (Customer customer in _customers)
            {
                CustomerViewItem customerViewItem =
                    Mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerViewItem>(customer);

                customers.Add(customerViewItem);
            }
        }

        private void RunManual(int count)
        {
            List<CustomerViewItem> customers = new List<CustomerViewItem>();
            foreach (Customer customer in _customers)
            {
                CustomerViewItem customerViewItem = new CustomerViewItem()
                {
                    FirstName = customer.FirstName,
                    LastName = customer.LastName,
                    DateOfBirth = customer.DateOfBirth,
                    NumberOfOrders = customer.NumberOfOrders,
                };

                customers.Add(customerViewItem);
            }
        }

        private Customer GetCustomerFromDB()
        {
            return new Customer()
            {
                DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1987, 11, 2),
                FirstName = "Andriy",
                LastName = "Buday",
                NumberOfOrders = 7
            };
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        public int NumberOfOrders { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerViewItem
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        public int NumberOfOrders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Output:**
 [image]

Why is would it take more time to map a single object than 10 or 100 even a 1000 objects? 
[Source](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/987284/Automapper-Performance-Testing)

Comment: You realize that the linked article is from 2015, and that there have probably been many updates to that library since then, yes?

Comment: So you tried mapping one object first. What happens if you map 10000 objects first? I bet it's just as slow, suggesting it does some one-time setup. I've never used Automapper, but that's the first thing I'd look into.

Comment: @mason I thought so too. I have updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: @KennethK. I just updated the automapper to the latest version. Same result.

Comment: You didn't reset your stopwatch between the first two runs.

Comment: @KennethK. same result even if i do

Comment: You're using an old version. Upgrade to the latest and check your results again.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I did. It still takes more time for the first mapping.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html). That shouldn't even be AM code, just compiling the expression. But only profiling would tell.

Answer (score 0):

If you reflect into the Mapper.Map method,I believe there is some caching going on with the first call, so after the first call, which caches the expression (taking more time) the rest do not have that overhead.

[image]

The above is from the MappingEngine class, which is referenced on the Mapper.Map calls.

```
var program = new Program();
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewItem>();

Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

for (int x = 1; x <= 100000; x *= 10)
{
    program.PopulateCustomers(x);

    watch.Start();
    program.RunMapper(x);
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("INITIAL :AutoMapper with {0}: {1}", x, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));


    watch.Reset();
    program.PopulateCustomers(x);

    watch.Start();
    program.RunMapper(x);
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("AutoMapper with {0}: {1}", x, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));

    watch.Reset();

    watch.Start();
    program.RunManual(x);
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Manual Map with {0}: {1}", x, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

[image]

Comment: I wrote the entire logging code block twice and got almost same result

Comment: Another user said you forgot to reset the watch. Once you reset the watch you will notice its correct.

Comment: same result even if i do

Comment: Its not. I copied your code and put the correct reset on the timer and 'AutoMapper with 1: is 0...

Comment: I just tried:
`  Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            program.RunMapper(1);
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("AutoMapper with {0}: {1}", 1, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));`

Got 200+ ms

Comment: Oh. Thanks. I am disappointed though. I was planing on using it in my project. But it seems that it has a lot of overhead. It's  30 ms on your machine. 100ms on mine. It doesn't matter if it takes 0 ms for consecutive requests. 100ms is a deal breaker.

Comment: Yeah, with the convenience comes a cost.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration.html#configuration-compilation